# How to apply ggplot on split dataset and combine the plots into a single grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create the plot between .resid and .fitted of each split dataset as shown below split tables and combine them into a single 2 x 2 plot. Any help? If I want to use bind_rows, how can I create a new column with cyl as an .id?

```r
library(datasets)
library(tidyverse)
ans_long = anscombe %>%
  pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to = c(".value", "set"),
    names_pattern = "(.)(.)"
  )

ggplot(ans_long, aes(x, y, color = set)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ set)
```

[image]

```r
ans_long %>% split(.$set) %>% lapply(\(k) lm(y ~ x, k)) %>% 
  map(broom::augment)
#> $`1`
#> # A tibble: 11 × 8
#>        y     x .fitted  .resid   .hat .sigma   .cooksd .std.resid
#>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1  8.04    10    8.00  0.0390 0.100    1.31 0.0000614     0.0332
#>  2  6.95     8    7.00 -0.0508 0.1      1.31 0.000104     -0.0433
#>  3  7.58    13    9.50 -1.92   0.236    1.06 0.489        -1.78  
...
#> 
#> $`2`
#> # A tibble: 11 × 8
#>        y     x .fitted .resid   .hat .sigma .cooksd .std.resid
#>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1  9.14    10    8.00  1.14  0.100    1.24 0.0523       0.970
#>  2  8.14     8    7.00  1.14  0.1      1.24 0.0523       0.970
#>  3  8.74    13    9.50 -0.761 0.236    1.28 0.0767      -0.704
#>  4  8.77     9    7.50  1.27  0.0909   1.22 0.0579       1.08 
...
#> 
#> $`3`
#> # A tibble: 11 × 8
#>        y     x .fitted  .resid   .hat  .sigma  .cooksd .std.resid
#>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1  7.46    10    8.00 -0.540  0.100  1.30    0.0118      -0.460 
#>  2  6.77     8    7.00 -0.230  0.1    1.31    0.00214     -0.196 
#>  3 12.7     13    9.50  3.24   0.236  0.00308 1.39         3.00  
...
#> 
#> $`4`
#> # A tibble: 11 × 8
#>        y     x .fitted  .resid  .hat .sigma     .cooksd .std.resid
#>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1  6.58     8    7.00 -0.421  0.100   1.30   0.00717      -0.359 
#>  2  5.76     8    7.00 -1.24   0.1     1.23   0.0623       -1.06  
#>  3  7.71     8    7.00  0.709  0.1     1.28   0.0203        0.605 
...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Use `map_dfr` and just pass the name of the new column to argument `.id`. From the documentation, my emphasis:

> .id
> Either a string or NULL. If a string, the output will contain **a variable with that name, storing either the name (if .x is named)** or the index (if .x is unnamed) of the input. If NULL, the default, no variable will be created.
> Only applies to ⁠_dfr⁠ variant.

```r
library(datasets)
library(tidyverse)

ans_long = anscombe %>%
  pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to = c(".value", "set"),
    names_pattern = "(.)(.)"
  )

ans_long %>% 
  split(.$set) %>% 
  lapply(\(k) lm(y ~ x, k)) %>% 
  map_dfr(broom::augment, .id = "set") %>%
  ggplot(aes(.fitted, .resid, color = set)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Anscombe's Quartet",
       x = "Fitted Values", y = "Residuals") +
  facet_wrap(~ set)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Beat me by seconds. To save one step we could use `map_df`.

Comment: @stefanYes, `map_dfr` would be better.